# how to round off to next 10 in oracle?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I need to find the next 10 digit number in a query.

I try to use round(n,-1) but it rounds off to nearest 10 digit but I need next 10 digit.

Please help me.

```
select round(5834.6,-1) from dual
```

gives 5830 but i need 5840

Comment: Add 10 to the number and round the sum.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select ceil(5834.6/10)*10 from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Then add "5":

```
select round(5834.6 + 5,-1) from dual
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm seems to suggest the rounding used by `ROUND` is datatype dependent...  4.999 then for other datatypes?

Comment: @fvu . . . The data type dependence has an effect only when the value is half-way between or one low-order bit away from that.  In any case, Sebas solution should meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution - Use MOD to find the last 10th place and then add 10 to the result.

```
select (5834.6 - MOD(5834.6,10)) + 10 from dual;
```

If you need the next 8th place, just replace any "10" with "8".

Answer (score -1):

`Select ceil(5834.6/10)*10 from dual;`